# Trying to force specific textbox rewrites

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have stumbled upon this particular code, and while I find it to be fully functional, I am trying to nitpick several parts of it in order to make it more user-friendly. That being said, I am trying to force some values in every textbox.

The first textbox is supposed to be a binary-only textbox, only 0s, and 1s allowed. The second and fourth textboxes are supposed to be octal and hex-based ones. My question is, how do I force rewrites on those textboxes? What I am trying to say is that I am looking for a property or event that erases my input if it doesn't match I want in the textbox.

If I type a letter or a number in the binary textbox, it should be erased.
If I type a number greater than 7 or a letter in the octal textbox, erased.
Hexadecimal = no letters other than A-F. And for decimal, no letters. I know how to exclude those values using and if and other nomenclatures, but I am truly lost when it comes to doing it for every textbox.

This is the code:

```
    window.onload = id;


function id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
function Convert(s, n)
 {
  if(parseInt(id(s).value, n)) 
  {
    if("bin" != s) { id("bin").value = parseInt(id(s).value, n).toString(2) }
    if("oct" != s) { id("oct").value = parseInt(id(s).value, n).toString(8) }
    if("dec" != s) { id("dec").value = parseInt(id(s).value, n).toString(10) }
    if("hex" != s) { id("hex").value = parseInt(id(s).value, n).toString(16) }
  } else 
  {
    if("bin" != s) { id("bin").value = "" }
    if("oct" != s) { id("oct").value = "" }
    if("dec" != s) { id("dec").value = "" }
    if("hex" != s) { id("hex").value = "" }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`onkeyup`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeyup.asp) event to listen to changes made by the user in an input box.

You could check with a REGEX expression that the string in your input box only contains `0`s and `1`s. If not then remove the last inputted letter:

```js
const check = e => {
  const value = e.target.value
  const isBinary = /^[0,1]+$/.test(value)
  
  if(!isBinary) {
    
    e.target.value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
  
  }

}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="check(event)">
```

Where `/^[0,1]+$/.test(value)` will return `true` if `value` only contains `0` and/or `1`, else it will return `false`.

Comment: Thank you, this should work wonders. I was actually unaware of that 'REGEX expression'. Much appreciated.